# Android - Navigation Graph preview screen orientation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

For some reason the navigation graph preview changed all the screen orientation of its fragment. Unfortunately I see no settings or way to change its orientation and get stuck. I am using Android Studio Dolphin Canary 7. How can I change the previews screen orientation back to portrait? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to press the letter "o" to switch between screen orientations in the navigation graph preview screen.

Comment: I already tried that but didn't work, anyway I solved it by restarting the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change any one of your layout file to phone inside **Device for Preview** option then those changes will automatically reflect on your nav graph.

*You can change as below image*

[image: preview]